# I want to hide kendo grid command edit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to hide kenod edit button with out removing it from code, I tried with adding a class with `display:none` and attribute `hidden:true` but nothing worked.
I need price button here but edit should be hidden.

```
  { command: ["edit",{text:"D" , click: deleteRow ,class : "k-grid-delete"} , {text:"Price" , click: showDetails ,class : "k-button"} ], title: "&nbsp;", width: "120px" }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the button to be hidden *conditionally*, you can use the `dataBound()` event:

```
dataBound: function (){
    var grid = this;
    var trs = this.tbody.find('tr').each(function(){
        var item = grid.dataItem($(this));
        if( item.Something == "Condition") {
            $(this).find('.k-grid-edit').hide();
        }
    });               
}
```

If you want to hide the button *indefinitely*, you can use the following CSS:

```
.k-grid-edit {
   display: none;
}
```

Here is an example which displays the [use of both methods](http://dojo.telerik.com/UgiYE/2) (I have initially commented out the CSS example to display the conditional hide functionality).

Comment: Excellent. Should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easier to set a variable in javascript true/false then set the command visible property to it.Then anytime you want your command to show just change the javascript variable.